# jQuery: How to write "src" attribute into Onclick function argument of child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, onclick

I'm using jQuery to rewrite the DOM to transform a no-JS HTML page into a JS-drive page. I've hit a glitch on transforming the image links. In the original code I have:

```
<div class="f">
   <a href="images/Fig-03-2.png" target="_blank">
      <img src="images/fig-03-2.png" alt="Fig 3.3" />
   </a>
</div>
```

...and I want to transform it into:

```
<div class="f">
   <a>
      <img src="images/fig-03-2.png" alt="Fig 3.3" onclick="imagepop("fig-03-2.png")/>
   </a>
</div>
```

I can't figure out how to write the `onclick` attribute so that it contains the `img src` value as `imagepop`'s argument.  I tried:

```
$(".f a").attr('onclick', 'imagepop(' + $(this).attr('src') + ')' );
```

...but `$(this).attr('src')` returned "undefined".

How should I fix my line of code or would it be better to read the `img src` attribute from inside the `imagepop` function?

**Note, I have not developed the page so that each div has a unique ID, and do not plan to do so.  None of the elements inside the `<div>` tag have IDs assigned to them.

Comment: You forgot to put quotes/escaping in the JS code string, so it comes out as `imagepop(http://www.example.com/images/fig-03-2.png)` which obviously won't work. However in any case setting event handler attributes from strings is wildly unreliable cross-browser and a bad idea in the first place. You can assign an event handler setting DOM `element.onclick` to a Function object, or you can do it the jQuery way as in TJ's answer, but avoid ever putting JS code in strings.

Comment: Also, please leave the `href`s in place so they still work as normal links that we can focus, keyboard-navigate middle-click-for-new-tab, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ...and I want to transform it into...

For what it's worth, I wouldn't. *Instead*, I'd use a function like this:

```
$("div.f a img").click(function() {
    imagepop(this.src);
    return false;
});
```

What that line, probably wrapped in a [`ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler, does is: If the user clicks the image, it does the `imagepop` thing and cancels the event, which (amongst other things) prevents the link from firing.

It's called *progressive enhancement*. JavaScript-enabled user agents will use the above, and ones without JavaScript enabled will still see and follow the link. Remember that user-agents are not just browsers, they include crawlers, spiders, etc., and yes, browsers with JavaScript disabled.

---

**Update**: If you really want to handle it at the link level (which might be more keyboard-friendly), rather than image level, then:

```
$("div.f a").click(function() {
    var img = $(this).find("img");
    if (img[0]) {
        imagepop(img[0].src);
        return false;
    }
});
```

...since it's the `img`, not `a`, element that has the `src`. (And no need to use `attr` here, the `src` reflected property is supported by all major -- and probably all minor -- browsers.)

Comment: okay - but I want the onclick handler to be on the `<a>` element, not the `<img>`.  How would you recommend changing that? `imagepop(this.("img").src);` ?

Comment: @Alien: I just thought you might want that and updated the answer. LOL! :-)

Comment: It works.  Thanks for the extra information about progressive enhancement, too.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$('.f a').onclick(function(e){
imagepop($(this).find('img').attr('src'));
e.preventDefault();
});
```

Basically, it selects all of the anchors under the `.f` class, and applies an `onclick` to each of them. inside the onclick function, we reference `this` which is the current anchor tag, and put it through a jQuery object. That allows us to find all `img` elements under that anchor tag, pull it's `src` attribute, and run it through `imagepop()`.

Comment: dang... I'm always too slow. =[

Comment: maybe, but I think I've seen a post or two of yours before